# Fortify Annotation to suppress Invalid Privacy Violation

Tags: java, annotations, fortify

I am trying to find API info for Fortify Annotations.  It's not anywhere in the Fortify User's Guide and I can't find it with a search on Google. Specifically, I want to see what available annotations there are.  Hopefully, there is one that can make Fortify suppress an invalid Privacy Violation. It thinks PII is being written out to a log, when in actuality it's just an error code value.

Comment: The Fortify Java annotations are available at support.fortify.com in the "Premium Content" section. This is not a widely used feature, so the documentation is a little sparse. You could also look at using a filter or custom rule instead of changing the code. If you post more info about the Privacy Violation finding I could help with that.

Comment: Requests for off-site resources will be closed: being specific as to what you're trying to find out is useful.